# Knockout Visible Binding After Page Load But Not Initially

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Suppose I have several fields on a page. When any of those fields are blank, I want to show a simple message. The problem is when I load the page with blank fields the message doesn't appear. However, if i update a field to have a value and then remove it, the message appears. So I know the binding is there and the function call is working as intended. My question is why is it not evaluated when the page is loaded?

The function "ContainsBlankLine()" simply loops through all the fields and returns true or false.

HTML

```
<div class="row information" data-bind="visible: $root.ContainsBlankLine()() == true">
       <div class="col-filler">
           <span>One or more fields have been left blank.</span>
       </div>
</div>
```

Code

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var vmCartIndex = function () { var self = this; };
        vmCartIndex = ko.mapping.childrenIndependently($.parseJSON('@Html.RawJsonForKoMapping(Model)'), ["Summary", "Header", "Items", "Footer"]);
        vmCartIndex.ContainsBlankLine = function () {
            return ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < vmCartIndex.Items.ItemsList().length; i++) {
                        var item = vmCartIndex.Items.ItemsList()[i];
                        if (item.Field() == '')
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }, vmCartIndex)
        };
        ko.applyBindings(vmCartIndex); 
 }); </script>
```

Comment: Why is `ContainsBlankLine` a function creating a computed? Why not just a computed? Separately, there's never any reason to write `== true`.

Comment: I can't guarantee the thing above wrt `ContainsBlankLine` isn't, in fact, the problem, but I can't guarantee it *is*, either. I suggest creating an [MCVE](/help/mcve) as a Stack Snippet.

Comment: Also, why are you assigning a function to `vmCartIndex` only to turn around and *replace* it with the result of `ko.mapping.childrenIndependently`? The first line is a no-op.

Comment: Best guess filling in the blanks, can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/j314r8fL/ Definitely need an MCVE (in a Stack Snippet in the question; I used a fiddle because this is a comment).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder rightly pointed out . #chad generalized version here http://jsfiddle.net/j314r8fL/2/ . cheers

Comment: I'll try and address all four comments in one response:
1 - The "why" is irrelevant. And "== True" has nothing to do with the solution either.
2 - Assume the vmCartIndex = ko.mapping line is fine. That goes deeper into the project but it essentially allows the named objects to be mapped independently of one another; that is I can refresh one subset of information on the view without reloading everything.
3 - This again has no relevance to the answer. The first line defines it.
4 - My question revolvs around when the binding occurs since on load the binding doesn't work but post load it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well as mentioned in the comments you can improve the code . Each and every point mentioned by  `T.J. Crowder` is true and used his initial fiddle to fork a bit (thanks)

**viewModel:**

```
var vmCartIndex = {
    Items: {
        ItemsList: ko.observableArray(
        [{
            Field: ko.observable("")
        }, {
            Field: ko.observable("")
        }, {
            Field: ko.observable("")
        }])
    }
};
vmCartIndex.ContainsBlankLine = ko.computed(function () {
    var result = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vmCartIndex.Items.ItemsList(), function (data) {
        if (!data.Field()) { //this bit identifies '',undefined,null
            return true;
        }
    });
    if (result) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}, vmCartIndex)

ko.applyBindings(vmCartIndex);
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/j314r8fL/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

In the script, the default value of the fields were null not ''. Therefore the first time I run the page the script comparison

```
 if (item.Field() == '')
       return true;
```

would never pass. Changing the script to the following resolved the issue.

```
 if (item.Field() == '' || item.Field() == null)
       return true;
```

Comment: haven't you checked the fiddle i gave in the comments ? `if` condition can be shortened not need to check '' , null . undefined etc you can use `if(!item.Field())` which is the same .

Comment: I didn't see that in your fiddle. If you want to add it as an answer I'll mark it as  such.

Comment: sure i'll add it as answer which will be useful to someone catching up later rather leaving code in comments .